# Getting Custom ContentType to Register with Auto-Completion in VSIX Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, vsix

I've written an extension to provide IntelliSense auto-completion for an VS Isolated Shell. The issue I'm having is making this auto-completion apply only to files of a particular file type. I've followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-linking-a-content-type-to-a-file-name-extension?view=vs-2017) to do so.

Relevant class file:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace VSIXProject1
{
    internal static class FileAndContentTypeDefinitions
    {

        [Export]
        [Name("assembly")]
        [BaseDefinition("text")]
        internal static ContentTypeDefinition hidingContentTypeDefinition;

        [Export]
        [FileExtension(".asm")]
        [ContentType("assembly")]
        internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition hiddenAVRASMFileExtensionDefinition;
    }
}
```

Despite this, when I put the `[ContentType("assembly")]` export on the ICompletionSourceProvider and the IVsTextViewCreationListener that are used to handle the IntelliSense integration, the auto-completion fails to show up at all. However when I use `[ContentType("text")]` or `[ContentType("plaintext")]` the auto-completion will show up on either all files or just .txt files, respectively.

This is the first VSIX plugin I've tried to make so maybe I've missed something. Currently, I'm at a loss for what to try next. A lot of googling hasn't yielded much information, and the code resources I have found seem to implement this behavior in the same way I'm attempting to.

Answer (score 1):

So after a few unsuccessful attempts, and a stroke of luck, I realized what my issue was. The specific Isolated Shell (Atmel Studio) I was trying to write the extension for already had a ContentType for assembly files. I'm guessing that when I added my own content type it was overwritten by the shell itself.

In order to fix the issue, I used the ContentType name that the shell uses which happened to be "assembler". This happened to be a lucky guess based on the languages that appear under Tools > Options > Text Editor. Hopefully, this helps someone who runs into the same issue in the future.